# What is the difference between "$line" and "^$line"

Tags: linux, bash, unix

There is a while read loop:

```
while read line; do
    grep "^$line" file1
done < target
```

I should use `"^$line"` to get the right answer. I want to know what is the difference between 
`"$line"` and `"^$line"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `while` loop is not relevant here, it's the `grep` command that make the `^` significant. The `^` character is a identifier in regular expressions. It matches the start of the line, Therefore `grep "$line" file` matches any lines in the file where `$line` is substring but `grep "^$line"` only matches those that start with `$line`.

Answer (score 1):

@sudo_O has the right answer for your question. However, you can omit the loop altogether:

```
grep -f target file1
```

It's way more efficient with just a single call to grep. If you need the line anchor:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' target) file1
```

Comment: Why the `sed 's/^/^/'` ?

Comment: That inserts a literal `^` character at the beginning of each "file1" line, to act as a regex line anchor for the grep call. in sed's `s///` command, the left-hand side is a regular expression and the right-hand side is just a string (with the exception of `&` and `\1` back references